# Execvp failed with errno 13 even in root on android arm64-v8a

Tags: android, c++, arm64

I try to execute a shell command from c++ on Android. I am compiling for arm64-v8a and armeabi-v7a. My Android device is rooted.

I don't understand why, but the following code works perfectly fine when I run the armeabi-v7a binary as root or non-root user and when I run the arm64-v8a as non-root user. But if I run the arm64-v8a binary as root user, it failed, I get :

```
EXECVP : -1
ERRNO : 13
```

```
int main()
{
    char* command[] = {
        (char*) "/sbin/su",
        (char*) "-c",
        (char*) "/system/bin/sh -c \"/system/bin/touch /data/local/tmp/foo\"",
        NULL
    };
    std::cout << "EXECVP : " << execvp(command[0], command) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "ERRNO : " << errno << std::endl;
}
```

I have also tried to work with the `system()` function or `popen()` but nothing solved my problem. I always have the same result : works perfectly with armeabi-v7a (root or non-root user) and arm64-v8a (non-root user) but systematically fails when I run it as root.

Comment: First of all, the value of `errno` is *undefined* if you call any other function that might change `errno` after the failed function call. And that is almost guaranteed to happen with the overloaded `operator<<` functions and flushing the buffers of `std::cout`. Call `execvp` separately, and check the result. If there's an error then save the value of `errno` immediately, without doing anything else first. *Then* you can use the saved value to report the problem. I also recommend you use `strerror(errno)` to get a short explanation about the error.

Comment: Thanks. I did what you advised. But I still get the same result.

Comment: At least you're guaranteed that you get the correct error. What does `strerror(errno)` tell you?

Comment: It tells "Permission denied"